# Select Max Date in either case statement or where clause

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 columns 1) id (int) and 2) Date. I want to select id on max date. Grouping results in returning both id's/more than one id. Instead i only want to retrieve id on max date .

Comment: please provide some sample data, is Id primary key?

Comment: studentid - 93207 ,Courseid- 16,19,20 Enddate - '2016-03-04', 2016-7-12',2016-01-03' references student table is = '93207',    I want to get output like  93207,19 ( selecting on max date)

Comment: @BHouse  Please edit your question to include this additional info, in the format it is held within your database.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: in addition to the request for sample data and RDBMS version, the query(s) you've tried so far and their (incorrect) results, plus what you're looking for as the correct/desired results

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is easier way to do this however below should work fine.

```
-- create sample data
create table #temp(ID int, courseID int, end_date datetime)
go
insert into #temp
select 1 , 11 , getdate() 
union
select 1, 12, getdate()-20
union
select 1, 13, getdate()-40
union
select 2, 13, getdate()-70
union
select 2, 14, getdate()-80

-- create temp table to calculate correct date
select id, max(end_date) as correctDate
into #temp2
from #temp
group by id

-- final desired outup
select #temp2.id , #temp.courseID
from #temp2
inner join #temp
    on #temp2.id = #temp.id
    and #temp2.correctDate = #temp.end_date

-- drop temp tables
drop table #temp
drop table #temp2
```

give me a shout if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

Simpler alternative

```
-- create sample data
create table #temp(id int, courseID int, end_date datetime)

go
insert into #temp
select
    1 , 11 , getdate() 
union
select
    1, 12, getdate()-20
union
select
    1, 13, getdate()-40
union
select
    2, 13, getdate()-70
union
select
    2, 14, getdate()-80


SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY end_date DESC ) sira, id,courseID,end_date  FROM #temp  
) t WHERE sira = 1

-- drop temp tables
drop table #temp
drop table #temp2
```